# UDP port forwarding not working with Docker on Windows 10

Tags: windows, docker, networking, snmp, alpine-linux

I am running a Docker container for snmptrapd.
It runs fine on a Linux host (Ubuntu 18.04), but not on Windows (10 Pro).

Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.8

RUN apk --no-cache add net-snmp

COPY mibs/ /usr/share/snmp/mibs
COPY snmptrapd.conf /etc/snmp/snmptrapd.conf
COPY snmp.conf /etc/snmp/snmp.conf

EXPOSE 162/udp

ENTRYPOINT ["snmptrapd","-L","o","-f"]
```

We also forward UDP port 162 in the Docker run command:

```
docker run -d --rm -p 162:162/udp snmp_server
```

A simulated SNMP trap originating from inside the Windows host reaches the container correctly.
**But any trap originating from outside the Windows host is not reaching the container.**

It is not a Windows firewall problem, because I can run Wireshark on the Windows host and see the traps arriving, destination port UDP 162, as expected.

After the container is started, netstat on Windows shows that there is a listener on UDP port 162, bound to all interfaces:

```
netstat -ano | findstr 162
UDP    0.0.0.0:162            *:*                                    13952
UDP    [::]:162               *:*                                    13952
```

Inside the container, netstat shows that there is a listener on UDP port 162, bound to all interfaces.

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:snmptrap        0.0.0.0:*
```

Docker version 19.03.1, build 74b1e89

I have tried:

- --network=host instead of the default bridge mode;
- --privileged
- --cap-add NET_BROADCAST

Grasping at straws at this stage!

Comment: Interesting. You _might_ have better luck on ServerFault tbh.

Comment: Did you find a solution? Seems like there is an ongoing issue with UDP ports and Docker for Windows. I can't get tftp, which uses UDP port 69, to work between a Windows host and Linux container.

Comment: Any update to this pickle?